# Can you print an image to the terminal using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

You can print to the terminal using 
    print("Hello World")
but can you print an image?  If you can, how?

Comment: you mean rendering image on console or printing the image data ?

Comment: What is your terminal?

Comment: the terminal cannot display images (in binary format) except if encoded (e.g as ascii art)

Comment: Rendering the image.  I use the Linux terminal.

Comment: related: [How do I make my terminal display graphical pictures?](http://askubuntu.com/q/97542/3712)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by `print an image` you mean displaying the pretty graphic, no.  If you mean printing something that kinda/sorta if you stand back a bit and squint looks like the image (otherwise knows as [ascii art](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII_art)), then yes -- if you have [a library that supports converting from binary](https://www.hackerearth.com/notes/beautiful-python-a-simple-ascii-art-generator-from-images/).

Comment: it depends on your environment e.g., [FIM supports Linux framebuffer device](http://www.nongnu.org/fbi-improved/#screenshots).

Answer (score 2):

It's possible with ANSI art (that use [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)), Check this JavaScript library
https://github.com/patmooney/node-terminal-art

[image]

or web browser that render web pages in terminal https://www.brow.sh/ (including images).

[image]

As you can see this is possible, terminal give you this, so you can implement such a library in any language or search if there is already one in Python.

**EDIT** some terminals also support [Sixel format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sixel) that allow o render bigger resolution images.